# Zizaco / entrust throws error with @permission in blade

Tags: php, laravel, rbac

I am using a package `Zizaco / entrust` for role-base access control (RBAC).

The user role checks in a view with `@permission`, Like wise,

```
@permission('role-create')
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('roles.create') }}"> Create New Role</a>
@endpermission
```

which is equal to,

```
<?php if (\Entrust::can'role-create') : ?>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="<?php echo route('roles.create'); ?>"> Create New Role</a>
<?php endif; // Entrust::can ?>
```

But it throws the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''role-create'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) (View: /var/www/rbac/resources/views/roles/index.blade.php)`

Comment: This is a bug with the package, https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php  If you scroll down to where the `permission` directive is being built, you can see someone forgot the `(`.  There is already a pull request for this https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/pull/667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug with in the package but you can fix it in your project 
go to vendors directory there find a entrust directory then from there go to src/Entrusts/EntrustServiceProvider.php

there you find your blade directive code like below

```
\Blade::directive('permission', function($expression) {
    return "<?php if (\\Entrust::can({$expression}) : ?>";
 });
```

there you see one starting bracket is missing after can simply add that starting bracket like below

```
\Blade::directive('permission', function($expression) {
     return "<?php if (\\Entrust::can({$expression})) : ?>";
 });
```

Or  Use with two parenthesis. Like this:
`@permission(('role-edit'))  @endpermission`

for further information please check the below link

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/657

**Note :** In prior versions of Laravel, when registering custom Blade directives using the directive method, the $expression passed to your directive callback contained the outer-most parenthesis. In Laravel 5.3, these outer-most parenthesis are not included in the expression passed to your directive callback. Be sure to review the Blade extension documentation and verify your custom Blade directives are still working properly.

Comment: dump the composer then check composer dump-autoload

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' (View: /var/www/rbac/resources/views/roles/index.blade.php)`

Comment: There are multiple broken things in that file.  You need to go through and fix them all.  Copy the contents of the file at https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/pull/667/commits/31e49abff10306a84eefe22504279b9eef000333 into the `EntrustServiceProvider.php` file you just modified.

Comment: just like user3158900 mention copy the code from that link and replace it with your file then check it

Comment: updated my answer now check it previously one end bracket is missing now i add that please check it now and then let me know

Answer (score 2):

Simply double the small brackets on your permission name that solve my problem

```
@permission(('role-create'))
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('roles.create') }}"> Create New       Role</a>
@endpermission
```